# Is it possible to limit iOS file sharing so that it is read only?

Tags: ios, objective-c, file-sharing

on iOS it is possible to enable file sharing from iOS apps to files within the Documents directory using `UIFileSharingEnabled` in the app's plist.

Is it possible to ensure that the directory is read only? This is so that files added to the directory from the app are visible to iTunes on a computer, but files cannot be dragged into the folder.

If so, how can this be accomplished?

Comment: Would [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32662729/ios9-filemanager-file-permissions-change) help?

Comment: yes, it's possible to share docs for read only. You have perform plist programming in  your app. Similar option is available when when any file show 'OpenIn' option.